# Stars and Bars Proof via Mathematical Induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I wish to prove a variant of Stars and Bars via induction. I already have a nice combinatorial proof.

Stars and Bars has the following equivalence that ${n+k-1}\choose{k-1}$ = ${n+k-1}\choose{n}$ via the elementary identity ${n}\choose{k}$ = ${n}\choose{n-k}$. (Thanks for the heads up @lulu!)

In my case, I have both $n$ and $k$ $\geq$ 2, so my basis step would be to prove the LHS equals the RHS for $n$ = $k$ = 2. Doing so gives 3 = 3, which is a true statement.

Induction says to assume the statement is true for $n$ = $k$ and demonstrate truth for $n$ = $k+1$. I feel that while simply substituting this into the binomial coefficient does indeed prove things, it seems too simple. That is,

${(k+1)+k-1}\choose{k-1}$ = ${(k+1)+k-1}\choose{n}$

${2k}\choose{k-1}$ = ${2k}\choose{k+1}$

Maybe its because induction is not typically used with these kinds of statements? Rather induction is always introduced as proving for instance that $\sum_{k=0}^n{k}$=$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

**Is my "proof" valid?**

Comment: It isn't that Stars and Bars "says" that, it's rather that this is a basic property of binomial symbols.  Indeed, $\binom ab=\binom a{a-b}$.  This follows instantly from the standard defining formula for the binomial symbol.

Comment: Right since the number of ways to include $k$ objects from a total of $n$ is equal to the number of ways to exclude $n-k$ objects from $n$. I suppose I should be more careful with my phrasing. Fixed.

Comment: Side note: the name "stars and bars" is becoming less preferred, because that phrase also refers to the flag of the Confederacy and thus celebrates the goals of that movement. "Sticks and stones" is my favorite name—there are others as well.

Comment: Whoa... I wasn't aware of that. I've heard the technique also being referred to as "Rice and Chopsticks", but I suppose this also brings negative connotations if one thinks about it.